# Save item from RecyclerView to Favorites

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm making an app that gets image , text, url from json url in recyclerview and display the text and image in cardview. and when the user will click on the item it will open new webview activity and pass the url to this activity . everything work fine . but now i want to make a favorite list and when user click on button on the recyclerview item it will save this item to the favorite list . and also the user can click on this item and open the webview activity as it is. i searched alot in the internet and i found that i need to use SQLite for this , but i can't find any good tutorial for this or any example .

i have already created the method setOnClickListener for the button in the Adapter but idk what to do next

any idea please ? and sorry for my english .

here is my code

HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private final String Data = "https://medicalibrary.net/wp-content/uploads/AaaLatestUpdatet.json";
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private ArrayList<Model> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;



    public static HomeFragment newInstans() {
        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        return homeFragment;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment_acivity, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        
        httpGet();


        return view;
    }

    private void httpGet() {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, Data, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Model model = new Model();
                        model.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                        model.setImage(jsonObject.getString("image"));
                        model.setUrl(jsonObject.getString("url"));

                        modelList.add(model);



                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
                        recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getContext(), modelList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("Tag", "onErrorResponse" + error.getMessage());
            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
}
```

Model.java

```
public class Model {
    String title, image, url;

    public Model() {
    }



    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }


}
```

RecyclerAdapter.java

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Model> modelList;


    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Model> listData) {
        this.modelList = listData;
        this.mContext = context;

    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.title.setText(modelList.get(position).getTitle());
        Picasso.get().load(modelList.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.imageView);

    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return modelList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        ImageView imageView;
        Button favBtn;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setClickable(true);
            mContext = itemView.getContext();

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String Url = modelList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getUrl();
                    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, WebViewActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("url1", modelList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getUrl());

                    ///  i.putExtra("url", Url);
                    mContext.startActivity(i);
                }
            });

            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Title);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
            favBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.favBtn);
            favBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    Model model = modelList.get(position);


                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

WebViewActitvity.java

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);



        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.mWebView);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String url = i.getStringExtra("url1");
        webView.loadUrl(url);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to look at the [Android Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) for saving your favorites list. SharedPreferences is another option.

From an architecture perspective, it would be beneficial for you to look into the repository pattern, which you can find [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide).

With this in mind, first, I would pass a listener to your adapter:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClicked(model: Model)
    }

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Model> modelList;
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public RecyclerAdapter(
        Context context, 
        List<Model> listData, 
        ItemClickListener itemClickListener
    ) {
        this.modelList = listData;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    ...

    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            itemClickListener.onItemClicked()
        }
    });
}
```

and then implement the listener in the `HomeFragment`:

```
class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements RecyclerAdapter.ItemClickListener {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(Model model) {
        viewModel.saveFavorite(model);            
        router.openWebView(model.getUrl());
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a click listener interface includes both fav and click action and pass the click events to activity or fragment.

You can use SharedPreferences, Room, Realm etc. to save your favourites. Here is a tutorial about this: https://medium.com/android-gate/recyclerview-item-click-listener-the-right-way-daecc838fbb9